# How to get rid of the margin in a figure saved by matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure saved as .png file by matplotlib of a matrix x:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1,1), dpi=100)
plt.imshow(x)
fig.savefig('filename.png')
```

This is the result, opened in Preview:

[image]

There is a white margin that I do not need, an my question is:

- how can I save the image in python without this margin?

P.S.: If I try the different solutions found in other posts, I don't get the result I need. For example the solutions:

```
fig.savefig('filename.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

or

```
fig.savefig('filename.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

give

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `bbox_inches='tight'` in `savefig`:

```
fig.savefig('filename.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it does not work for my image..no idea why